# Posicionar o cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função com JQuery que deixa o texto do textbox em uppercase, o problema é que quando tenho uma mascara no campo, após digitar qualquer caractere, o cursor vai para o final do textbox, ai o usuário tem que voltar e digitar novamente, e o cursor volta para o final, isso só acontece em campos com mascara, segue a função.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
// Chamada da funcao upperText(); ao carregar a pagina
upperText();
// Funcao que faz o texto ficar em uppercase
function upperText() {
    // Para tratar o colar
    $(":input").bind('paste', function (e) {
        var el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            var text = $(el).val();
            el.val(text.toUpperCase());
        }, 100);
    });

    // Para tratar quando é digitado
    $(":input").keypress(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            var text = $(el).val();
            el.val(text.toUpperCase());
        }, 100);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro que você use a função `change()` do JQuery. Ela é chamada quando o algo é digitado ou colado ou etc. Assim você não precisa de timeouts e não precisa de duas funções para fazer a mesma coisa.https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Obrigado deu certo, como o change() é executado após o elemento perder o foco não tenho problema com o cursor nos campos com mascara.